# Golang how to pass username and password as JSON body to Post API

Tags: json, rest, go, command-line, command-line-arguments

Using a post API request I want to receive a JWT token for the response.

For that, I want to send the *username* and *password* as JSON body input to the API. The *username* and *password* should be taken dynamically from the user as a JSON payload.

Currently, I am hardcoding the user name and password using **strings.NewReader** which is not suitable as this is a web application and many users will be using it.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

var authToken string

type authorization struct {
    AuthorizationToken string `json:"authorizationToken"`
    ExpiresTimestamp   string `json:"expiresTimestamp"`
}

func main() {

    enverr := godotenv.Load(".env")

    if enverr != nil {

        fmt.Println("Error loading .env file")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    token()
}

func token() {

    authorizationUrl := os.Getenv("authorizationUrl")

    requestBody := strings.NewReader(`

        {
            "name" : "testuser",
            "pwd" : "testpwd",
            "hName" : "hname"
        }
    `)

    response, err := http.Post(authorizationUrl, "application/json", requestBody)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()
    content, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)

    var result authorization
    if err := json.Unmarshal(content, &result); err != nil { // Parse []byte to the go struct pointer
        fmt.Println("Can not unmarshal JSON")
    }
    authToken := result.AuthorizationToken
    fmt.Println(PrettyPrint(authToken))
}

func PrettyPrint(i interface{}) string {

    s, _ := json.MarshalIndent(i, "", "\t")
    return string(s)
}
```

Comment: How would you want to have the data (username / password) fed to you API? Could add the current implementation and add more clarity atop?

Comment: @tmarwen added the code I am currently trying to use. As I requested above I wanted the user to pass their own json payload while trying to use this API

Answer (score 1):

You can use http requests body (for POST request)

```
type Credentials struct {
    Username    string `json:"username"`
    Password    string `json:"password"`

}

c := Credentials{}
decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
defer r.Body.Close()

err: = decoder.Decode(&c)
if err!=nil{
  // handle it
}

// use it 
fmt.Println(c.Username, c.Password)
```

Comment: getting this error while trying with above "r.Body undefined (type string has no field or method Body)"

Comment: @trick001 do some changes to handlerFunc to this work. For example if there is a handler func which handles your request. `func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { // use r.Body}`

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to distribute the application as an executable (aka command line in the Unix world), you can either:

- Provide the *username* and *password* as program arguments, `os.Args` (omitting unchanged code):

  ```
    var inputTemplate = `

        {
            "name" : "USER",
          "pwd" : "PWD",
          "hName" : "hname"
        }
    `

    func token() {

        authorizationUrl := os.Getenv("authorizationUrl")

        requestBody := strings.Replace(strings.Replace(inputTemplate, "PWD", os.Args[2], -1), "USER", os.Args[1], -1)

        response, err := http.Post(authorizationUrl, "application/json", requestBody)
        // ...

    }
  ```

  You should then be able to run your program (once compiled): `./filename user password`
- Or as better alternative, having sensitive data involved, have the *username* and *password* input from *standard input* with password being echoed (hiding the characters):

  ```
    import (
      // ...
      "syscall"
      "golang.org/x/term"
    )

    var inputTemplate = `

        {
            "name" : "USER",
          "pwd" : "PWD",
          "hName" : "hname"
        }
    `

    func token() {
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Print("Enter username: ")
        username := reader.ReadString('\n') // handle error
        fmt.Print("Enter password: ")
        pwdbytes := term.ReadPassword(int(syscall.Stdin))
        password := string(pwdbytes)

        authorizationUrl := os.Getenv("authorizationUrl")

        requestBody := strings.Replace(strings.Replace(inputTemplate, "PWD", password, -1), "USER", username, -1)

        response, err := http.Post(authorizationUrl, "application/json", requestBody)

        // ...
    }
  ```